# What are some software examples to sketch out a website or app UI, updating the content is irrelevant and can remain static

Tags: web-development, user-interface, visual-design

I have been working for a couple months on a new website/app idea. I have finished the design process but now I need to create a user friendly demo to show to people to gather some data/feedback and eventually demo it to investors. I am looking for a good software to design the UI. I'd like to focus on how the buttons, links, labels, text-boxes work together, ignoring the content (it can remain static) Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "best"? Please remove the word "best" and replace with more specific terms, thanks! Also, it is OK if everything is static, for instance a news feed always shows the same news, and nothing can be modified or posted by the user?

Comment: Also, please limit your question to websites, otherwise it is far too broad. Then ask us to reopen.

Comment: It is ok if the website is static, it will only be used as a design proposal. I worry more about it properly showing how the buttons and text-boxes and those (UI) elements work together. The content is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks! Finally, what is your budget? Must it be gratis for instance? And should the website be responsive design, I mean show cleanly on both desktop and mobile, or will you create a separate website for mobile if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Adobe XD](https://www.adobe.com/products/xd.html). It is a drag-n-drop prototyping application for mobile apps and websites. It is intended for designers that have no programming experience, and it really is amazing how powerful it is for creating a professional prototype.

Adobe offers XD for free, so you can download it and do the tutorial. You'll see how easy it is to make something impressive in ten minutes.

Comment: I like how you are able to display how the buttons, textboxes and all those UI elements work together without focusing too much on the content. Perfect for a design proposal.

Comment: @elias Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I recently worked on a project where the designers used Invision. So I didn't create the designs, but I was able to comment on the designs and make change requests. The designers were not developers and only did interface design and mockups with invision.

So you could do a mockup without programming anything and present the basic app to investors.

https://www.invisionapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what technology stack you want to use long term.

Back in the day, I would simply use Visual Studio to develop my wireframes, which allowed me to transition from wireframe versions to functional software very quickly.